# Having issue in combining 2 paragraph together into 1 paragraph

Tags: python, string

I'm scraping some data and the data is coming to me as two paragraphs which are then stored in one variable broken up into two lines. I want to store the data without line breaks to look like one paragraph.

I tried the `strip` and `join` functions but it didn't work for me.

```
# Assume that these are the two paragraphs 
str = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry"
"Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s"

mystr=" ".join(str.split())

print(mystr)
```

which should print

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
```

Comment: Don't name your variables (`str`) the same as built-in data types.

Comment: "I'm scraping some data and the data is coming to me as two paragraphs which are then stored in one variable broken up into two lines" Can you describe this a bit more? This seems to be your problem here, as having a simple string sitting on a line by its own does not assign it to any variable.  Also, you have not described what issue you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want...

```
string = """
"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry"
"Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s"
"""

mystr= str.replace('"','')
mystr = mystr.replace('\n','. ')

print (mystr)
```

This code removes the quotes from the string, then changes the newlines to a period and a space, so the output is

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
```

Comment: If you're gonna wrap strings inside a string, then why aren't you simply putting them in a list?